# Privacy Policy and Terms of Use for subdomains in USA

Tags: subdomain, legal, privacy, terms-of-use, privacy-policy

I have a site which has two sub domains. One is forum and another is listing site. 
The main site has privacy policy. Do I need to have separate privacy policy and term & conditions page for each sub-domain or every thing has to be added on root domain.

Comment: Sorry but the usage of privacy policies and so forth change from one country to the next depending on who sets the law on how information is used and stored, because of this its unlikely to help other visitors or its likely to give the wrong information. Your welcome to narrow down your question to the usage of a privacy and terms of use that is required by law in a specific region or country.

Comment: This question is not related to one site only, Many sites has sub domains and will help others also.

Comment: No where in the question I have mention my site name.

Comment: It depends tho. If the listing page is just a white screen with a bunch of clickable links (similar to an apache's directory listing page), then you may get away without Privacy Policy and Terms and Conditions. but for every page that is fully complete and presented to the end user, there needs to be at least a Privacy policy/Terms and Conditions so users can understand all legal aspects in relation to the site including how their info is used.

Answer (score 3):

Terms of Services and Privacy Policies depend on the legal entity *behind* a website. They shouldn't be done based on how domain or subdomain are structured.

I mean: if your forum is managed and owned by the same entity of the main domain, you don't need to have them separate. It's enough to have 1 privacy policy and 1 terms of service page.

But remember that your Privacy Policy page and Terms Of Services pages should include forum and listing sites terms and policies, and they should be linked to from both.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have separate Privacy Policy and/or Terms of Use.

These legal agreements are binding between the company that operates the website/mobile app and users.

If multiple subdomains and main websites are operated and owned by the same company, then the company can have just *one* Privacy Policy and *one* Terms of Use.

What you should look after is:

- Making sure that both legal agreements are based on what personal information you collect, use and store from all subdomains and websites.

  For example, if you collect location data from a subdomain, but not from another, your Privacy Policy should mention this.
- That you link to both legal agreements from all subdomains and websites since they share the same agreements.